# How do I change where my scratch buffer is saved?

Tags: emacs

How do I change where my scratch buffer is saved? (I ask because I rsync a couple of folders between multiple computers and would like the scratch buffer to come along for the ride.)

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to your `.emacs` file should do the trick.  Obviously customize the file for the scratch buffer.

```
(defvar scratch-buffer-file-name "~/sktch.el"
  "file name for *scratch* buffer")

(defun synch-scratch-with-file ()
  "replace *scratch* buffer with the file scratch-buffer-file-name"
  (save-window-excursion
    (find-file scratch-buffer-file-name)
    (kill-buffer "*scratch*")
    (rename-buffer "*scratch*")
    (lisp-interaction-mode)))
(synch-scratch-with-file)
```